# conflitos de menus no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theme, template

Bom dia a todos!! 
pessoal, eu criei um tema para uma loja e está funcionando tudo certo, mas agora precisei criar um segundo menu(para o rodapé)e quando crio os links, o primeiro menu(do topo) fica com os links do segundo, que está no rodape...
eu estou chamando os menus dessa forma:

menu do topo :

`<?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=>'Topo') ); ?>`

menu do rodape:

`<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'rodape')); ?>`

e na criação deles eu estou fazendo assim:

```
register_nav_menu('menu_principal', 'Menu Principal - Topo');
register_nav_menu('menu_home', 'Menu home - lateral');
register_nav_menu('rodape', 'menu na parte do rodape');
register_nav_menu('erro', 'erro');
```

enfim, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, alguém tem alguma sugestão?
Obrigado pela atenção!!
Horácio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta chamar dessa forma:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu_principal' ) ); ?> // para menu topo

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'rodape' ) ); ?> // para menu rodape
```